# What does the RepublishAll switch do in the SPE Publish-Item command?

Tags: publishing, powershell-extensions

I suppose one should take the name of the switch at "face value", but it's difficult when there's *already* a `PublishMode` parameter which defines how the command is intended to work.

So, I guess more specifically, if I invoke the following command:

```
Publish-Item master:/sitecore/content/Home -Recurse -PublishMode Full
```

How is it different from the following command?

```
Publish-Item master:/sitecore/content/Home -Recurse -PublishMode Full -RepublishAll
```

Answer (score 2):

`PublishItemCommand` passes this parameter to `PublishOptions` which are used while publishing.

And `PublishOptions.RepublishAll`, according to Sitecore documentation:

> Gets a value indicating whether all data in all languages will be published.
>
> This is a special mode of publishing used for completely rebuilding a web database.
>
> `true` if all languages will be published; otherwise, `false`